# php preg_match spacebar detour

Tags: php, security, preg-match

I was learning the php vulnerabilities.
and I have a php code like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['hi']) &&
!preg_match("/work/i", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) &&
$_GET['hi'] === 'work hard')
echo "DETOUR SUCCEED" ?>
```

I want to echo "DETOUR SUCCEED"

I've been searching for ways to detour the preg_match. But I could not.

I think this preg_match is vulnerable because of a space between work and hard. But I'm not sure.
Please help me figure out

Comment: You're checking three conditions to get to that code. One of them is that the string *doesn't* contain "work", one of them is that the string is "work hard". That code will never execute.

Comment: What is the content of `$_GET['hi']` and `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`?

Comment: @Toto ?hi=work hard

I guess?

Comment: You guess !!  Print them to be sure.